# ParamSpec for a pre-defined function, without using generic Callable[P]

Tags: python, python-typing

I want to write a wrapper function for a known function, like

```py
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
         foo()
         return known_function(*args, **kwargs)
```

How can i add type-annotations to `wrapper`, such that it exactly follows the type annotations of `known_function`

---

I have looked at `ParamSpec`, but it appears to only work when the wrapper-function is generic and takes the inner function as argument.

```py
    P = ParamSpec("P")
    T = TypeVar('T')
    def wrapper(func_arg_that_i_dont_want: Callable[P,T], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs)
         foo()
         return known_function(*args, **kwargs)
```

Can i force the `P` to only be valid for `known_function`, without linking it to a `Callable`-argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PEP 612 as well as the documentation of `ParamSpec.args` and `ParamSpec.kwargs` are pretty clear on this:

---

> These “properties” can only be used as the annotated types for `*args` and `**kwargs`, accessed from a `ParamSpec` already in scope.

- Source: [PEP 612](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/#id1) ("The components of a ParamSpec" -> "Valid use locations")

---

> Both attributes require the annotated parameter to be in scope.

- Source: [`python.typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec.args) module documentation (`class typing.ParamSpec` -> `args`/`kwargs`)

---

> They [parameter specifications] are only valid when used in `Concatenate`, or as the first argument to `Callable`, or as parameters for user-defined Generics.

- Source: [`python.typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec) module documentation (`class typing.ParamSpec`, second paragraph)

---

So no, you cannot use parameter specification `args`/`kwargs`, without binding it a concrete `Callable` in the scope you want to use them in.

I question why you would even want that. If you **know** that `wrapper` will **always** call `known_function` and you want it to (as you said) have the exact same arguments, then you just annotate it with the same arguments. Example:

```py
def known_function(x: int, y: str) -> bool:
    return str(x) == y


def wrapper(x: int, y: str) -> bool:
    # other things...
    return known_function(x, y)
```

If you *do* want `wrapper` to accept *additional* arguments aside from those passed on to `known_function`, then you just include those as well:

```py
def known_function(x: int, y: str) -> bool:
    return str(x) == y


def wrapper(a: float, x: int, y: str) -> bool:
    print(a ** 2)
    return known_function(x, y)
```

If your argument is that you don't want to repeat yourself because `known_function` has 42 distinct and complexly typed parameters, then (with all due respect) the design of `known_function` should be covered in copious amounts gasoline and set ablaze.

---

If you *insist* to dynamically associate the parameter specifications (or are curious about possible workarounds for academic reasons), the following is the best thing I can think of.

You write a protected decorator that is only intended to be used on `known_function`. (You could even raise an exception, if it is called with anything else to protect your own sanity.) You define your wrapper *inside* that decorator (and add any additional arguments, if you want any). Thus, you'll be able to annotate its `*args`/`**kwargs` with the `ParamSpecArgs`/`ParamSpecKwargs` of the decorated function. In this case you probably *don't* want to use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) because the function you receive out of that decorator is probably intended not to replace `known_function`, but stand alongside it.

Here is a full working example:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Concatenate, ParamSpec, TypeVar


P = ParamSpec("P")
T = TypeVar("T")


def known_function(x: int, y: str) -> bool:
    """Does thing XY"""
    return str(x) == y


def _decorate(f: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[Concatenate[float, P], T]:
    if f is not known_function:  # type: ignore[comparison-overlap]
        raise RuntimeError("This is an exclusive decorator.")

    def _wrapper(a: float, /, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        """Also does thing XY, but first does something else."""
        print(a ** 2)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return _wrapper


wrapper = _decorate(known_function)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(known_function(1, "2"))
    print(wrapper(3.14, 10, "10"))
```

Output as expected:

```
False
9.8596
True
```

Adding `reveal_type(wrapper)` to the script and running `mypy` gives the following:

```
Revealed type is "def (builtins.float, x: builtins.int, y: builtins.str) -> builtins.bool"
```

PyCharm also gives the relevant suggestions regarding the function signature, which it infers from having `known_function` passed into `_decorate`.

But again, just to be clear, I don't think this is good design. If your "wrapper" is not generic, but instead always calls the same function, you should explicitly annotate it, so that its parameters correspond to that function. After all:

> Explicit is better than implicit.

- [Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python), line 2

Comment: Thanks, works as expected. Both pycharm and mypy suggests and catches errors as expected. The use case is like you say to avoid repeating 42 parameters into known_function, but i have no control over the upstream definition of it since it comes from a third party library. Hence need for wrapper in first place.

Comment: @HTE I see. In that case, I would still suggest, writing out the wrapper's arguments explicitly because you'll only be doing it once. Moreover, this gives you more freedom, if you decide to omit a few parameters or change their defaults. IDE helpers will be more useful then. But you do you.

Comment: no need for the abrasive language. `ParamSpec` seems to have been made for this use case, but forgot the simple case where the function is known.

Comment: "If your argument is that you don't want to repeat yourself because `known_function` has 42 distinct and complexly typed parameters, then (with all due respect) the design of `known_function` should be covered in copious amounts gasoline and set ablaze." I agree that functions like `subprocess.run` should go.

Answer (score 2):

if the parameters match exactly you can use this 1-1, if there's a mismatch you would need to also use `Concatenate` and modify it a bit, i have yet to find a generic solution for that case. this is a modified version of the above answer from `@Daniil Fajnberg`

```py
from typing import TypeVar, ParamSpec, Callable

P = ParamSpec("P")
T = TypeVar("T")
S = TypeVar("S")

def paramspec_from(_: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[[Callable[P, S]], Callable[P, S]]:
    def _fnc(fnc: Callable[P, S]) -> Callable[P, S]:
        return fnc
    return _fnc
```

then you can use it like this:

```py
@paramspec_from(known_function)
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> string:
    foo()
    known_function(*args, **kwargs)
    return "whatever"
```

The problem is that mypy only looks at the function header to resolve the ParamSpec, not the function body, so it cannot deduce the types of args and kwargs. but if we lift the function into the header, like by passing it into the decorator as an argument, mypy can deduce the parameters correctly. As you see we don't even use the function, we marked it with `_`. we only use it for its typehints.

Comment: if we would have access to a curry wrapper that preserves typehints we could simplify to:

```def paramspec_from(_: Callable[P, T], fnc: Callable[P, S]) -> Callable[P, S]:```
and avoid that akward typehint in the first wrapper