Preserving typing/typechecking while extending function with many arguments
I want to subclass/wrap subprocess.Popen. However, it has a lot of arguments. The usual ways to solve this, as far as I'm aware, are 1. "biting the bullet":
class MyPopen1(subprocess.Popen):
    def __init__(self, myarg1, myarg2, bufsize=-1, executable=None,
                 stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None,
                 preexec_fn=None, close_fds=True,
                 shell=False, cwd=None, env=None, universal_newlines=None,
                 startupinfo=None, creationflags=0,
                 restore_signals=True, start_new_session=False,
                 pass_fds=(), *, user=None, group=None, extra_groups=None,
                 encoding=None, errors=None, text=None, umask=-1, pipesize=-1,
                 process_group=None):

        arguments = self.handle_custom_arguments(myarg1, myarg2)
        super().__init__(arguments, bufsize, executable,
                 stdin, stdout, stderr,
                 preexec_fn, close_fds,
                 shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines,
                 startupinfo, creationflags,
                 restore_signals, start_new_session,
                 pass_fds, user=user, group=group, extra_groups=extra_groups,
                 encoding=encoding, errors=errors, text=text, umask=umask, pipesize=pipesize,
                 process_group=process_group)

or 2. using *args, **kwargs.
class MyPopen2(subprocess.Popen):
    def __init__(self, myarg1, myarg2, *args, **kwargs):
        arguments = self.handle_custom_arguments(myarg1, myarg2)
        super().__init__(arguments, *args, **kwargs)

The second is a lot easier to write; it requires no maintenance if a new argument is added to subprocess.Popen in 3.1x. The downside is that it has no types, which means no static typechecking and no function signature hinting in a text editor.
We can get a little closer with @functools.wraps(...), but at the cost of the signature needing to be the exact same as subprocess.Popen, and it overriding doc and etc. I don't think it's what wraps is intended for.
# Not good solution.
class MyPopen3(subprocess.Popen):
    @functools.wraps(subprocess.Popen.__init__)
    def __init__(self, myarg1: int, myarg2: str, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        :param myarg1: does foo
        :param myarg2: does bar
        """
        arguments = self.handle_custom_arguments(myarg1, myarg2)
        super().__init__(arguments, *args, **kwargs)

Ideally, I'd want a type signature like...
def __init__(self, 
             myarg1: int, myarg2: str, 
             *args: ArgsOf[subprocess.Popen.__init__][1:], 
             **kwargs: KwargsOf[subprocess.Popen.__init__]):

Is there any way to get this sort of effect? If not, how can I preserve typechecking when doing something like this?

Dump of potentially useful links: https://github.com/python/typing/discussions/1079 https://discuss.python.org/t/proposal-add-bound-to-paramspec/39979/6 https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/17119 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74714300/paramspec-for-a-pre-defined-function-without-using-generic-callablep https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spec/generics.html#paramspec

Possible duplicates: Copy type signature from another function, Python Typing: Copy `**kwargs` from one function to another, How to copy method type hint with decorator in Python?, How to override a class __init__ method while keeping the types, etc.

You can use Unpack[] from the typing library to grab type hints from a TypedDict:
from typing import TypedDict, Unpack

class Movie(TypedDict):
    name: str
    year: int

def foo(**kwargs: Unpack[Movie]) -> None: ..

https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spec/callables.html#unpack-kwargs
But given that this still makes you explicitly lay out all params in a new object, I'm not sure how much lift this is going to give you - the first method might be more expedient.

I'm not sure if there's all-round type-checker support for what you want to do here, but here's something that half-works* on mypy (see mypy Playground):
from __future__ import annotations

import typing_extensions as t

import subprocess


if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    import collections.abc as cx

    _P = t.ParamSpec("_P")


class MyPopen(subprocess.Popen[str]):
    @classmethod
    def create(
        cls: cx.Callable[_P, MyPopen],
        arg1: str,
        arg2: bytes,
        /,
        *args: _P.args,
        **kwargs: _P.kwargs,
    ) -> MyPopen:
        Cls: type[MyPopen] = cls  # type: ignore[assignment]
        self = super(MyPopen, Cls).__new__(Cls)
        cmd_: str = self.handle_custom_arguments(arg1, arg2)
        super(MyPopen, self).__init__(cmd_, *args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
        return self

    def handle_custom_arguments(self, arg1: str, arg2: bytes, /) -> str:
        return ""

>>> reveal_type(MyPopen.create("", b"", "<args>", encoding="locale"))  # MyPopen
>>> MyPopen.create(1, b"", "<args>", encoding="locale")  # Wrong first argument
>>> MyPopen.create("", b"", "<args>", cwd=[1], encoding="locale")  # Wrong keyword argument

Since class constructors are usually special-cased by type-checkers, it's unlikely you can do this with __init__ or __new__ directly, so a @classmethod could be the next best solution.
The idea is that a type object (here, cls) can act as a factory (Callable[_P, <instance type>]), so we make cls generic with respect to the factory's signature (_P) and use it to type *args and **kwargs.

*Pyright seems to freeze on this example, and mypy will only match the first overload.
